# Implement ΔList

Tags: code-golf, math, array, arithmetic

Given a list of integers, such as `{1, 4, 2, 8, 10}`, TI-Basic's `ΔList` will determine the difference between every overlapping pair of items. In the given example, it would be `{3, -2, 6, 2}`.

**Task:**

Take a list of integers as input, in any reasonable way. All overlapping pairs `{x, y}` should become `y - x`, and the resulting list returned. It should always be one item shorter. You can assume the list will never be shorter than two items.

**Test cases:**

```
{1, 2}                  {1}
{1, 2, 4}               {1, 2}
{2, 1}                  {-1}
{2, 2, 2}               {0, 0}
{-1, 0, 0, -1}          {1, 0, -1}
{0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0}      {1, 1, -1, 0, -1}
```

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer (in bytes) per language wins!

Comment: Is the `{2, 2, 2}  -> {0, 0, 0}` testcase correct? Shouldn't the output be `{0, 0}`?

Comment: @Delfad0r Fixed

Comment: sub-problem of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47005/67312).

Comment: Instead of overlapping pairs `{x, y}` becoming `{y - x}`, can they become `{x - y}`? e.g. `{1, 4, 2, 8, 10} -> {-3, 2, -6, -2}`

Comment: @AaronMiller No, sorry.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of [Different Way Forward](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47005/67312), as this is essentially the same task, but to only do one step

Answer (score 6):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>33 26</s></sup> 25 bytes

```
qqjYkPJr-0C<c-r>=<c-r>"
<Esc>j@qq@qdd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwKzI7wKtI18DZJlm3yM4WTCpx2bgWJ9tlORQWOhSmpPz/b8Bl@F@3DAA)

Input as a newline separated list of integers.

-7 bytes from kops.

-1 more byte from kops.

### Explanation

```
qqjYpkk:s/\n/-
qq             start macro q
  jYp          go down and duplicate the second line from the cursor
     kk        move back to the original position
       :s/\n/- replace newline with -
               Current Line: n1-n2

C<c-r>=-(<c-r>") 
C                cut current line, enter insert mode
 <c-r>=          evaluate the following
       -(<c-r>") negate n1-n2

<Esc>j@qq@qdd
<Esc>         exit insert mode
     j        go 1 step down to the next values
      @qq     recursively call macro q and end macro
         @q   call macro q
           dd delete last extra line
```

Comment: [-7 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwKzIg26tI28DZJlm3yM5WF0wpcdm4FifbZTkUFjoUpqT8/2/AZchlBMSGXAb/dcsA)

Comment: @kops thanks. I should use `Jr` in my other answers as well.

Comment: [Found one more byte](https://tio.run/##K/v/v7AwKzI7wKtI18DZJlm3yM4WTCpx2bgWJ9tlORQWOhSmpPz/b8BlyGUExIZcBv91ywA)

Answer (score 4):

## Trivial answers

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0NL//6MNdRSMdBRMYgE)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 4 bytes

```r
diff
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfYvs/JTMt7X@KRrKGoY6JjpGOhY6hgabmfwA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```r
I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z/8Odix81zK19uGPRwx1dD3fMf9S4Lexw@9FJD3fO4Hq4e8vh9kdNayL//6821FEwqlXAANWGtVxgOR0Fk1oMOZAermqgnCE2rbqGEEkjLEZXG@goGACldYFmGICRLrIZ1YYwMS6QSogDDMHIoBahxBCkBKYSAA)

Feel free to add your answers here.

Comment: What is a 'trivial answer'?  5 bytes = 5 commands for APL, or 4 bytes = 4 functions for Jelly seems quite a lot...  Are there special 'brownie points' for outgolfing a 'trivial answer'?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Hmm, you're right. Maybe I should remove the APL and Jelly (and maybe the Husk) answers, at least for now?

Comment: They are pretty simple, and that's mostly why they are there. You can probably find most of these as part of many, many answers.

Comment: A "trivial answers" CW answer should consist of just builtin answers. Not only does this not contain it, but it doesn't even have the literal Jelly builtin for this

Comment: I've removed them now

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 82 bytes

```
\d+
$*
¶.*
$&-$%`
^.*¶

%(`^((-1+)|(1*)-)-(1*)$
$2$3$4
(1*)-+\1
-
--|-$

1`1*$
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCcNADETvU4fW7EdaVhv3kAJyNUaB5JBLDiFH1@UC3NhGDo/HwAzM5/l9ve8jxJvxWB4FlHHsNYMmoWBYaz52IERbYxQtaYuakyQ5g0CdLjTj35VFIRDZhAA1zT7XaaSr@SN4KHe4PKOzug5EuTmiaHxu6rQf) Takes input on separate lines but test suite converts from and to comma delimited for convenience. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
¶.*
$&-$%`
```

Create expressions for the differences of successive terms. `` $%` `` grabs the previous term without having to match it.

```
^.*¶
```

Delete the first term.

```
%(`
```

Perform the rest of the script individually on each subtraction.

```
^((-1+)|(1*)-)-(1*)$
$2$3$4
```

If the two values have different signs then negate the second and add it to the first.

```
(1*)-+\1
-
```

Otherwise subtract the two values.

```
--|-$
```

The subtraction can result in a double negative or a trailing subtraction of zero which needs to be removed.

```
1`1*$
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

Comment: This question's been closed for nearly four hours (nice answer though!)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.slice(1).map((v,i)=>v-a[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDsIgEEX3noIlJEA7jVt6kaYLgtRgsDTWsDGeHYFWo8JkVp/3hn@RXq7qZpY7m91Jh0kEKXrJV2uUxkD4VS4Ye2qI6D2TgxlJUG5endXcujOe8AAUdSMh6HuaBj3geaiQFB1/4EzGvIAjCbWzDGpo918ioS1FaQuewfZAEft8sffIWSHEdOsOedsk7QIk4e2FFw)

---

#### JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(v=>-p+(p=v),p=a.shift())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDsIgEEX3noIlRKCdxi29iHFBatGaWkhp2BjPjkCrUWEyq897w79JJ203D2Zhkz73XgkvRSv5XRrsRMvMHhvhCDVCcnsd1IIJ8Z2erB57PuoLVvgIFDUnQtD3VBV6wHNXICk6/MCJDHkGBxJKZxmU0Oa/RERriuJmPIP1gSL2@WLrkbJMCOnaHdLWUdoEiMLb8y8)

#### JavaScript (ES10), 34 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.flatMap((v,i)=>i?v-a[i-1]:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDoMgEEX3PQVLSEAd01UT7Al6AsNiYrWhMWLUsGl6dgpom7Y4mdXnveHf0eLcTHpcxGCureukQ1lh1vW4XHCk1HLNZKXPVmCtBahTrZhrzDCbvs16c6MdrYGTUjFGvifPyQOehx2Sk@MPHEmfJ7AnYe@sgD20/C8R0IKTsAkvYH3gRHy@2HrELBF8unaHuEWQNgGC8PbcCw)

Comment: I don't think it can get much shorter than this...

Answer (score 3):

## APL 5 bytes

```
2-⍨/⎕

    ⎕ ⍝ input
 -⍨   ⍝ reversed subtraction
2  /  ⍝ between every 2 elements like [1,2,3] -> [1 f 2, 2 f 3]
```

[try it online](https://abrudz.github.io/ngn-apl/web/index.html#code=%u2395%u21902-%u2368/%u2395)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda s:[y-x for x,y in zip(s,s[1:])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKrpSt0IhLb9IoUKnUiEzT6Eqs0CjWKc42tAqVjP2f0FRZl6JRppGtIGOgqGOghGYBCKDWE3N/wA)

-8 bytes thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKrpSt0IhLb9IoUKnUiEzT6Eqs0CjWKc42tAqVjP2f0FRZl6JRppGtIGOgqGOghGYBCKDWE3N/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩＥΦθκ⁻ι§θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQMMtM6cktUijUEchW1NHwTczr7RYI1NHwbHEMy8ltQIiDgLW//9HRxvqKJjoKBjpKFjoKBgaxMb@1y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input array
  Φ         Filtered where
    κ       Current index is not zero
 Ｅ          Map over remaining elements
      ι     Current element
     ⁻      Subtract
        θ   Input array (still with zeroth element)
       §    Indexed by
         κ  Current index
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 17 bytes

```hs
zipWith(-)=<<tail
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BDoIwDIbve4rGmABxU2a8yXwC7x7mDgsOWRy4yA7gwzs3CNFEm17a7@@X1rK7KWN8xc7@qe1JuzolGSsKJ7XxjdQtu9wRpBrfs4JUjbQQybqzsk03LBFJViwPV@WOulUIjHLQs4eSl6VerRZisR/GCYLDPnTr0ipwNuAeDxmC6PecYtgK@ClOBRoZhp34YfEG8cDov1NCJ7j9o@Y5hjxgEhz52OTbwem8QzE5PUDHzsUnQmNkTr7Kyshr50lp7Rs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
IƝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z2Nz///8b6CgY6igYgUkgMgAA)

Full program, as it relies on Jelly's outputting format.

This applies `I` (forward differences) to each overlapping pair `[x, y]` (`Ɲ`), yielding `[y - x]` for each. Due to Jelly's printing, as a full program, it omits the brackets around single element lists, so the output looks like a flat list.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

Non-builtin approaches. All are functions

```
_ƝN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@2Fy//w93Ln7UMLf24Y5FD3d0Pdwx/1HjtrDD7UcnPdw5g@vh7i2H2x81rYn8/7/aUEfBqFYBA1Qb1nKB5XQUTGox5EB6uKqBcobYtOoaQiSNsBhdbaCjYACU1gWaYQBGushmVBvCxLhAKiEOMAQjg1qEEkOQEphKAA)

```
_@Ɲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/e4djc/w93Ln7UMLf24Y5FD3d0Pdwx/1HjtrDD7UcnPdw5g@vh7i2H2x81rYn8/7/aUEfBqFYBA1Qb1nKB5XQUTGox5EB6uKqBcobYtOoaQiSNsBhdbaCjYACU1gWaYQBGushmVBvCxLhAKiEOMAQjg1qEEkOQEphKAA)

```
IƝF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z2Fy3/w93Ln7UMLf24Y5FD3d0Pdwx/1HjtrDD7UcnPdw5g@vh7i2H2x81rYn8/7/aUEfBqFYBA1Qb1nKB5XQUTGox5EB6uKqBcobYtOoaQiSNsBhdbaCjYACU1gWaYQBGushmVBvCxLhAKiEOMAQjg1qEEkOQEphKAA)

### How they work

They all use the `Ɲ` quick, which takes a link before it (a command, usually an atom) and a list, and applies the link to all overlapping pairs in the list.

`_` is subtraction in Jelly, and `@` reverses the order of the arguments to the previous link.

The first one calculates `x - y` for each overlapping pair, then negates each.

The second calculates `x -@ y` for each overlapping pair, which is equivalent to `y - x`

The third applies `I` (forward differences) to each pair, yielding `[y - x]`. We then flatten this into a single array.

Comment: Hm...  Just when I was wondering what did and what did not qualify as a 'trivial' answer...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I didn't edit this into the CW answer because I think they should be for builtin-only answers, which this one clearly isn't. If it were edited to remove the APL and Jelly answers, I might

Comment: (only the first one - ```I``` - was there when I commented: I assume that counts as a built-in, right?  The others all look perfectly valid to me... well done [unless there's a 2-byter that you're missing...])

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yeah, I don't think you can get more "builtin" than 1 byte in Jelly :P

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
head((x=scan())[-1]-x,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyM1MUVDo8K2ODkxT0NTM1rXMFa3QkfXUPO/oYKJgpGChYKhwX8A)

The [R](https://www.r-project.org/) 'trivial' answer is `diff` (difference).

So this is my attempt at the golfiest solution *without* diff...

Comment: There are lots of longer ones without `diff`, including [my favorite](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyUzMV0jv7QktUijwka3ODkxT0NTp0JHSVdJM1rXUCdW87@JgpmChYLlfwA), but I haven't been able to find a shorter one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
Differences
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yUzLS21KDUvObX4f0BRZl6JgkO6Q7WBjoKhjoIRmAQig9r//wE)